# Xamarin.android supporting different screen size

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem with working on some different screen sizes. I implemented some buttons in my Main.xaml and added folders (layout-sw320dp, layout-480dp and layout-600dp with Main.xaml inside of each folder).

Problem is when i am building an app on my samsung galaxy s6 it uses 320dp, and when i am building it on a device with 720x1280 resolution it uses 600dp.

These folders are inside my Resources folder

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Bump? Really need help guys ;/